# Show a product which belongs to Default category

Tags: magento-1.9, product, category, 404

First of all, my intention is to create a product which does not belong to any category because it is a special onw.

As I known in Magento, all products must belong to some category so I have tried to set it to the Default Category with no succeed because when I try to access to the product by url it show the 404 Magento error page.

Is it possible to have a product not being assigned to any category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access any product by it's url. It's **not necessary** to assign it to a Category.

But you should confirm OR make sure you have set proper product attributes, like:

- Status
- **Visibility**
- Quantity
- Stock Availability
- **Websites** (you have to select a website when you run multi
  stores/websites)

After editing/saving category, indexing should be done and clear/refresh cache.

Comment: It's working now, I think the problem was I forgot to index, just refresh cache the time I created the product. But I could not see it when it was set on Default Category, this time that it is not set to any category it works.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can access product by url which is not assign to any category. Please make sure product which you added is not disable or out of stock and all required attributes are assigned properly.

Comment: It's strange then, because I can not acces to it. I have tried putting it in one of my categories and it works, it shows up. As soon as I remove it from the category, or set it to the default category, when I access it, I get the 404 error. Thank you for answering.